# Is where are a new version of Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects than 1.2.1

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

Microsoft publiched the [`Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004) at 2011.

Is where are a new version of it?

Is where a another way to work with MS Exchange from desktop without Outlook installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.21 has been the CDO version for the last 15 years or more. It refers to the CDO functionality. It is not a build number.

The version you refer to is 6.5.8244.0. The latest version is 08.03.0.8353.000 released in March 2014: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040

Keep in mind that it's been on extended support for a while and no changes are expected.